# How to refer to files in dart?

Tags: image, file, dart, filesystems, filepath

I want to convert an image to Base64, I know most of what I have to do, but how do I reference the file?
The occurring Error is "**OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2**"
**In what directory should "bild.jpeg" be?
The same as the dart file?**

this is my code

```
main() {
  final bytes = File('bild.jpeg').readAsBytesSync();

  String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
  print(img64.substring(0, 100));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about what specific problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

The Dart `dart:io` library resolves files paths relative to the *current working directory*. You can find that directory as [`Directory.current`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-io/Directory/current.html).

Where that directory is depends on how you start the Dart script. If you run it from a shell (bash/cmd.ext), the current working directory will be the current directory of the shell. That's convenient because it allows you to create scripts in Dart that an be used like:

```dart
dart somewhere/script.dart foo.txt bar.txt
```

and act on the `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` of the current directory, just as most other shell scripts do.